# how to use string builder to append double quotes and 'OR' between elements

Tags: java, arrays

This is my code where I will get set of values in a list array.

how to use string builder to append double quotes and OR between all those elements and save to a string?

Also is it possible to get the elements in a split? For example I will get:

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j
```

in an array I want the output as

```
"a" OR "b" OR "c" OR "d"
```

and remaining elements in another iteration. As there are 10 elements I want 5 elements at at time in above format. Is it possible in string builder. Here in my example I have mentioned total as 10 elements but I actually get more than 1000 elements. Here is my code.

```
List<String> test = new ArrayList<String>();
while (rs.next()) {
    String url = rs.getString("rssUrl");
    test.add(url);
}
```

Comment: If you are doing this to build an SQL query then you should consider using a PreparedStatement instead. Constructing an SQL query like this  might be vulnurable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `StringBuilder` is a good idea when concatenating in a loop, as it will have better performances than the simple `String` concatenation. Here is a sample code as how to do it, using `StringBuilder` and modulo operation to check how many elements you want in the result:

```
final int nbElems = 5;
List<String> test = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j".split(",")));

StringBuilder sb = null;
for (int i=0; i<test.size(); i++) {
    if (i%nbElems==0)
        sb = new StringBuilder("\"");
    else
        sb.append("\" OR \"");
    sb.append(test.get(i));
    if (i%nbElems==(nbElems-1) || i==(test.size()-1)) {
        sb.append("\"");
        final String result = sb.toString();
        System.out.println(result); // TODO: do something
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
"a" OR "b" OR "c" OR "d" OR "e"
"f" OR "g" OR "h" OR "i" OR "j"
```

Comment: here a,b,c,d,e,f,j will be coming from query, List<String> test = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j".split(","))); how to re write this line according to it

Comment: @user3467677 You can just use the code you had in the question instead, the only thing this code does is putting all the elements in an `ArrayList`, exactly like what is done in the question.

Comment: Thank you very much yarr, it worked, you are awesome, one more question will both the rows come at a time or one at at time I need one at at ime

Comment: @user3467677 You'll have the rows one at the time where there is a `TODO: do something` in the code. If you want, you can store them in a `List` to use them latter, or just use them as they come.

Comment: No I want in a string I will be using this in a query as string, can you let me know how do I call this for loop one at a time in other class

Comment: @user3467677 You have two choices: store all the `String`s in a `List<String>`, and pass this `List<String>` to the other class, and in the other class iterate over the list and do a query for each `String`. Or, just call the method of the other class every time you have a `String`, with this `String` as parameter.

Answer (score 2):

```
String base = "a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j";
String[] letters = base.split(",");
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
    if (i > 0)
       builder.append(" OR ");
    builder.append("\"").append(letters[i]).append("\"");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to get it, there are some others:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(String.format("\"%s\"", list.get(0)));
    for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
         sb.append(" OR ").append(String.format("\"%s\"", list.get(i)));
    }

    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

The output should be:

```
"a" OR "b" OR "c" OR "d" OR "e" OR "f" OR "g" OR "h" OR "i" OR "j"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my contribution using split and `String`.

```
String[] letters = "a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j".split(",");
String concat = "";
int index = 0;
int itemPerLine = 5;

while(index < letters.length) {
    concat += "\"" + letters[index] + "\"";
    index++;
    if (index%itemPerLine == 0 || index==letters.length){
        System.out.println(concat);
        concat = "";
    } else {
        concat += " OR ";
    }
}
```

As requested, it outputs :

```
"a" OR "b" OR "c" OR "d" OR "e"
"f" OR "g" OR "h" OR "i" OR "j"
```